# How do I create one specific directory with Automake?

Tags: build, makefile, directory, automake

I just want to know what do I need to write in the `Makefile.am` to create a directory called `build` in the same directory where `Makefile.am` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write:

```
build:
    test -d ${srcdir}/build || mkdir ${srcdir}/build
```

but you really do not want to do that.  The source directory should be considered read-only.  If you simply want to create a directory named build in the build directory, just do

```
build:    
    test -d build || mkdir build
```

Comment: The thing is that I have already tried that, so I don't understand why I'm not able to do it. Correct me if I'm wrong. I run:

1) ./autogen.sh
2) ./configure
3) make

But I just got this: "the object directory "build/" cannot be found"

Comment: What is in your autogen.sh?  What is in your Makefile.am that is trying to reference the `build` directory?  Normally, the user would create the directory with something like `mkdir build; cd build; /path/to/configure && make`.

Comment: In Autogen nothing really. But in Makefile.am I'm trying to compile all my files.c and put them in this new build dir and have like a shared library for the binaries.
The thing is I'm creating the "build" dir manually, which is easier, but I thought I could do it on AM.

Answer (score 3):

Think about your question carefully: Do you really want to create `build` in the same directory as `Makefile.am`, or in the current working directory when `configure` is called? These are not always the same thing: the GNU build system is meant to support out-of-tree builds (with a potentially read-only `$srcdir`), so the end user should expect the following to work:

```
$ tar xf autofoo-1.2.tar.gz
$ mkdir autofoo-build
$ cd autofoo-build
$ ../autofoo-1.2/configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Now, the easiest way I have found to create a directory is not to use Makefile.am at all, but instead to make `config.status` do it (which is the shell script that does all of the template substitutions at the end of `configure`, turning `Makefile.in` into `Makefile`, `config.h.in` into `config.h` and so on). In `configure.ac`, put the following:

```
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS([mkdir], [$MKDIR_P build])
```

Comment: Excellent answer, but you could have used a better *tag* than `[mkdir]` which is confusing and looks like a command. For the readers the documentation is there: https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.60/html_node/Configuration-Commands.html

Comment: How do you do it if you want a directory created at install time?  For example, you want to create a directory in /usr/local/lib/mypackagelibdir and copy your staff there. This dir is different from the normal object libs, such as some perl modules boo.pm you want to copy to /usr/local/lib/site_perl

Comment: Maybe even better than `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS([mkdir], [$MKDIR_P build])` is simply `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS([build/mkdir], [true])` to let autoconf generate the `build` directory.